# Keyboard overflows text field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout

I'm not sure whether this is a bug from Flutter or not but when I try to tap on a text field (placed in my widget tree), the keyboard is overflowing it. See :

[image]

Using this simple code :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: 'App',
  home: Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 500, bottom: 100),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, bottom: 100),
        child: TextField(),
      ),
    ),
    // resizetoavoidbottominset: false // Same with or without this one.
  ),
);
```

I'm using Flutter 1.17.0 btw, with no error found (using both `doctor` and `analyze`). Btw, I ran some tests yersteday (if anyone is interested) :

- I've tested on both Android 10 and Android Marshmallow for the same result.
- If I try to implement `WidgetsBindingObserver` in order to listen to `didChangeMetrics`, the method never gets called.

I've never encountered this sort of problem using Flutter 1.12.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a physical device running Android 10.
Are you using an emulator?

Comment: Yes : `Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)`.

Comment: I just tested this on an emulator and I'm still unable to recreate it. Is your android emulator up-to-date? I have version 30.0.5.

Comment: Yep, `30.0.0-rc4` for me !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was using :

`<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">`

As a theme in order to disable system overlays. Now if I'm using :

`<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">`

Then it works perfectly.